# Validación de fecha Materialize (datepicker)

Tags: javascript

Requiero validar fecha con el calendario de materialize, tengo dos fechas. Fechas incial y fecha final la validación consiste en que la fecha final debe ser mayor que la inicial. Dejo el codigo acá https://gist.github.com/LeonardJAvi/6e41b447f061165fb4d4768f7e3ad501

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar la libreria moment.js para trabajar con fechas.
Aquí tienes una función a la que le pasas la fecha seleccionada en el Datepicker.
La función comprueba que entre la fecha actual y la seleccionada ha pasado como mínimo 1 día. Si es así, devuelve true, si no false.

```
function comprobarMayoria(dateSelected){                   
    var fechaseleccionada = moment(dateSelected, "DD-MM-YYYY");
    var dias = moment().diff(fechaseleccionada , 'days');
    return dias > 1 ? true : false
};
```

Espero que te sirva